# The meta-data tag in AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

The problem I have is that I had an older version of google play services set up with my app to be used for ads, everything was fine and this version of the app is currently in production on google play. I havent updated any code since a newer version of google play services came out and when I try to update something I get this error when I test on a device that has the most recent version of google play services:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 4242000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.U(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.a(Unknown Source)
```

and this is what my AndroidManifest looks like:

```
....
<application
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
....
```

I suspect the problem is that I am compiling with an older version of google play services, and because of that im getting the error, but what I do not understand is as far as I am aware my current version in production was built with the older google play services version and I do not have any crash reports that are from this error, and I am assuming that by now most if not all devices have the latest version so by following previous logic they too should also crash because of this. So is it necessary to change the google play services project I use to build any time there is a new one available, or will an older one still work? I don't see why the older version should not still work.

Note: Hard-coding the meta-data tag to what it expects "4132500" for the version of google play services does solve the problem for now, however I do not know if this is necessarily the correct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You linking a wrong version google-play-services.jar.
You should use the jar from **android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar**

Use the version number from **android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml**

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error. I just moved the 2 < meta-data > lines (name & valve) to the bottom above the configChange lines in the < application > and now it works again. No other changes.